# Get first item from Split()

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I use the [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) function to split a string which looks something like `1.23/1.15`.

Right now it yields two cells, as it should. But how do I get a certain element from the result? I would like to do something like this:

```
SPLIT("1.23/1.15", "/")[0]
```

to extract `1.23`. What is the correct syntax for that?

I tried using the `INDEX` function, without success: `=INDEX(SPLIT("1.23/1.15", "/"), 0,0)`

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You can use the index function to select which value to return. So to retrieve the second value from your example you could use:

```
=index(SPLIT("1.23/1.15", "/"), 0, 2)
```

The last argument says which `column` you wish to retrieve - `1` would retrieve the first value.

Alternatively you could use `left` / `right` and `find` to extract either value from your example. For example to get the first value you could use:

```
=left("1.23/1.15", find("/", "1.23/1.15"))
```

Comment: Oh, I just presumed index was zero-based. Thanks

Comment: I tried `left`/`right` with `split` and it always returned the 1st value. Just a heads up for anybody out there not noticing that you need to use `find` instead.

Answer (score 46):

The problem with the above two solutions is they are not supported inside an arrayformula function.  If you wrap in a query function, you get the desired result and is very flexible in terms of parsing just the field you are looking to return:

Return 1st Column

```
=query(SPLIT("1.23/1.15", "/"), "SELECT Col1")
```

Return 2nd Column

```
=query(SPLIT("1.23/1.15", "/"), "SELECT Col2")
```

Comment: if you want to use it in an arrayformula remember to set header to empty : 
`=query(SPLIT("1.23/1.15", "/"), "SELECT Col1 label Col1 '' ")`

Answer (score 8):

Additionally, if you would like to apply this to a range, you can use:

```
 =index(split(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""),"/"),0,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the array version that doesn't require a `QUERY` (proposed by @user3626750 ) and works inside `ARRAYFORMULA`. For example for extracting the first column of `SPLIT` result:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="","", FILTER(SPLIT(A1:A,"/"),{1,0})))
```

For the second column just replace `{1,0}` with `{0,1}`.

[image: sample]