# Is there an easy way to extract text from Google Sheets URL preview descriptions?

Tags: google-sheets, url

When hovering over a URL in Google Sheets, a preview is now displayed showing a short description of that link. Is there any way to retrieve that preview text native to Google sheets or with a script / extension?

Example use case: extracting the URL preview for an instagram page then using regex to get the follower count.

[image: image of URL preview]

I could only find information in google documentation about creating these previews (smart chips) but couldn't see anything about how one might get information back out from them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract link details from cell in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72110388/extract-link-details-from-cell-in-google-sheet)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.